# Adding KeyInfo reference in SOAP request in Java

Tags: java, signature, digital

I am wanting to add a reference within KeyInfo but can't seem to find a way to do it through code.

Here is what the expected output should be:

```
<KeyInfo>
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityTest" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
```

And I do have this above where it is trying to reference from:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
        wsu:Id="SecurityTest">Base64CertStuffBlahblah
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I am not able to generate the KeyInfo with SecurityTokenReference in Java.
Please let me know if anyone has any idea on this